# manage neo4j cross relationship in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, neo4j, relationship

I start recently to work with Neo4j database and i'm trying to display a graph using d3js (i'm new with it too!).

For my test i used the movie example data include in neo4j.

Using JQuery ajax and neo4j REST API, i find a way to make it more or less work.

But currently i can't make an actor link to several movie (or i duplicate them!).

here is currently my Cypher request:

```
match (a)-[r]->(m) RETURN {id: id(m), name: m.title}, collect({name : a.name, id: id(a)})
```

and the answer i get look like this:

```
{
"columns" : [ "{id: id(m), name: m.title}", "collect({name : a.name, id: id(a)})" ],
"data" : 
    [ 
        [ 
            { "id" : 3, "name" : "The Matrix Reloaded" }, 
            [ 
                { "id" : 5, "name" : "Keanu Reeves" }, 
                { "id" : 6, "name" : "Laurence Fishburne" }, 
                { "id" : 7, "name" : "Carrie-Anne Moss" } 
            ] 
        ], 
        [ 
            { "id" : 4, "name" : "The Matrix Revolutions" }, 
            [ 
                { "id" : 5, "name" : "Keanu Reeves" }, 
                { "id" : 6, "name" : "Laurence Fishburne" }, 
                { "id" : 7, "name" : "Carrie-Anne Moss" } 
            ] 
        ], 
        [ 
            { "id" : 2, "name" : "The Matrix" }, 
            [ 
                { "id" : 5, "name" : "Keanu Reeves" }, 
                { "id" : 6, "name" : "Laurence Fishburne" }, 
                { "id" : 7, "name" : "Carrie-Anne Moss" } 
            ] 
        ] 
    ]
```

}

So i'm thinking of 2 workarounds : either i find a way in d3 to do it (but i have a real hard time to understand d3js for this) or i change my cypher request to get the relationship in a different way.

i can of course make a huge workaround in javascript but my objective is to keep the code as much effective as possible (at the end i want to use it to get a lot of data).

i use the example here : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130
where i modify the flatten function like this (and some other minor change) :

```
// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;
    root.data.forEach(function(l) {
        var childrenlist = [];
        l[1].forEach(function(actor) {
            var ac = { name: actor.name, id: actor.id };
            childrenlist.push(ac);
            nodes.push(ac);
        });
        var movie = { id: l[0].id, name: l[0].name, children: childrenlist };
        nodes.push(movie);
    });

    return nodes;
}
/*! end of flatten */
```

So ! since i have a hard time with d3js, i'm looking a way to make my cypher request to give me the relationship info in a different way. more like this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

i'm really stuck because i don't know how to build my cypher request! 
i'm looking for a way to get the relationship source and destination node id and the node list but i don't know how to do both!

i want to mix this 2 requests:

```
match (a)-[r]->(m) RETURN {id: id(m), name: m.title}}
```

and something like this (but i don't know how to get relationship source and dest):

```
match (a)-[r]->(m) RETURN {src: id(r.src), dst: id(r.dst)}
```

if you could help me it would be awesome ! i hope i'm clear enough.

of course i'm open to any other suggestions or leads!
Thanks in advance!